# Call to a member function connection() on null Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Try write a unit test and i need do sql query

```
class UpdateThrowsTest extends TestCase
{

protected $bgame;
protected $game_id = 95;

public function setUp(){
    $game = new Game();
    $game = $game::find($this->game_id);
}
}
```

and then i write "phpunit" in console and try exception

Call to a member function connection() on null.

Comment: You need to setup the database connection for the tests.

Comment: thanks, but i don`t now how :(

Comment: You can set the default database connection in the .env file. But typically we set a different database for testing, which would be defined in the phpunit.xml.

Comment: From your code it kinda feels like you're new to testing. Testing involves working with a completely decoupled database from your main database. You generate data in the test and and use it to run more tests or other conditions. Though for a starter, you don't have to worry too much. But you should definitely read a bit more about testing.

Comment: this is my first test

Comment: where i have to write new connection to test db in my phpunit.xml?

Comment: <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>

Comment: also if you define setUp() you have to do parent::setUp() inside that method because TestCase uses it.

Comment: You can setup test database with this in your phpunit.xml

`<php>
 <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
 <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
 <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
 <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
 <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
 <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>`

Also be sure to use database migrations in your test. Check this link for more information.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing

Comment: i just need create new constants in my .end file ? UNIT_DB_NAME = mydb_test ?

Comment: i have done 

    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name = "DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql" />
        <env name = "DB_HOST" value="localhost" />
        <env name = "DB_DATABASE" value="sfc_unit" />
        <env name = "DB_USERNAME" value="root" />
        <env name = "DB_PASSWORD" value="123" />
    </php>

and my problem not resolve

Answer (score 21):

If anyone bounce to this error during test with Laravel 6 project.

Try to check if the **extends TestCase** is using the right TestCase.
It could be due to Laravel 6 make:test generated test using the wrong TestCase.

Change

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

To

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

The problem should solve.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I spent days trying to figure out why our tests wouldn't run in Laravel 6.

Answer (score 0):

You `setUp` method should call `setUp` method on the parent class.

So declaration should looks like this:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $game = new Game();
    $game = $game::find($this->game_id);
}
```

The same valid for `tearDown` method.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error on laravel 7 (nothing worked even php artisan serve) and fixed it with

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Before that update my vendor with composer update and then everything worked fine.

Comment: You are answering a question that was asked 3 years ago for laravel 5.4 plus I am very certain this is not the solution to the question (database connection problem, not a classloading one)